# On Async IO Completion

Tags: asynchronous, io, operating-system

I wondered how data is available on completion of a successful async IO (read) request. I mean does the requested data exist in the device buffers or in memory (somehow cached)?

For example, when my async callback is triggered (by the OS) which is informing me about data is ready, am I gonna be provided a file handle (points to the device) to initiate data transfer or, I will already have the data in the callback (which sort of means data is in the memory).

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @user3344003 I updated the question a little bit more. Hope it's far clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specifies what system you are using. In all systems that I have used that support asynchronous I/O, one calls a system service and provides a user buffer to store the data in.

The programming trick is that,  when the software interrupt occurs notifying the application of I/O completion, the application has to match the I/O request to the buffer.

Invariably, such system services include a parameter to pass some application ID that is in turn passed to the software interrupt handler called when the I/O completes.

SO usually your data will be in the buffer waiting for you.